# Нужно узнать какой QComboBox выбрал пользователь

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox

Есть программа на *Python* с использованием *PyQt5*.

Имеются **три** `QComboBox`:

- `ComboFizAkt` - уровень физической активности, в котором **4** варианта выбора.
- `ComboCel` - цель (хочу похудеть, хочу улучшить фигуру и т.д.), в котором **3** варианта выбора.
- `ComboTrenirovki` - кол-во тренировок в неделю, в котором **7** вариантов выбора.

Мне нужно узнать какой комбобокс выбрал пользователь, для того чтобы я мог использовать выбор в коде.

```
self.LvlFizAkt.setText("Уровень физической активности:")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Сидячий")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Слабый физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Преобладает физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Тяжёлый физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Очень тяжёлый физ. труд")
self.ViborCeli.setText("Ваша цель:")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Ничего не хочу")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу похудеть")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу улучшить фигуру")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу набрать мыш. массу")
self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText("Кол-во тренировок в неделю:")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("0")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("1")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("2")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("3")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("4")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("5")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("6")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("7+")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick, всё, что могу предоставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        self.comboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboFizAkt.addItems(
            ["Сидячий", 
             "Слабый физ. труд", 
             "Преобладает физ. труд",
             "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"
            ]
        )
        self.comboCel = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboCel.addItems(
            ["Ничего не хочу", 
             "Хочу похудеть", 
             "Хочу улучшить фигуру",
             "Хочу набрать мыш. массу"
            ]
        )
        self.comboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboTrenirovki.addItems(
            ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7+"]
        )        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Проверить выбор пользователя")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.comboFizAkt.activated.connect(self.label.clear)
        self.comboCel.activated.connect(self.label.clear)
        self.comboTrenirovki.activated.connect(self.label.clear)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Уровень физической активности:"), self.comboFizAkt)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ваша цель:"), self.comboCel)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"), self.comboTrenirovki)  
        layout.addRow(self.button) 
        layout.addRow(self.label)        
        
    def onClicked(self):
        text1 = self.comboFizAkt.currentText()
        text2 = self.comboCel.currentText()
        text3 = self.comboTrenirovki.currentText()
        self.label.setText(f'''
        {text1}
        {text2}
        {text3}
        ''')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но как сделать так:
Допустим, если пользователь выбрал вариант "Ничего не хочу", нужно вывести
print(123)

Comment: @vis-a-vis вы об этом ничего не писали в вопросе. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Я считаю, что на текущий вопрос я ответил.